# how to get google custom search result in json array

Tags: android, json, google-custom-search

I want to get google search results as json arrays in google latest custom search.

How to implement the code.

**For Example :**

```
 {
    "responseData": {` `
        "results": [
            {
      ` `          "GsearchResultClass ": "GwebSearch",
                "unescapedUrl": "http:/ / en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Hilton",
                "url"   : "http    ://    en.wikipedi a.org/wiki/Paris_Hilton",
                "visibleUrl  "  : "en.wikipedia .org",
                "cacheUrl    "    : "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:TwrPfhd22hYJ:en.wikipedia.org",
                "title": "<   b>Paris Hilton</b   > - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
                "titleNoFormatting": "Paris Hilton - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
                "content": "[1] In 2006, she released her debut album..."
            },
            {
                "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                "unescapedUrl": "http://`   `www.imdb.com/name/nm0385296/",
                "url": "http://`    `www.imdb.com/name/nm0385296/",
                "visibleUrl":     "www.imdb.com",
                "cacheUrl":      "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:1i34KkqnsooJ:www.imdb.com",
                "title": "<b>    Paris Hilton</b>",
                "titleNoFormatting": "Paris Hilton",
                "content": "    Self: Zoolander. Socialite <b>Paris Hilton</b>..."
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want a custom search result.
Please read `Custom Search Engine (free)` of Google at:

[Create custom search engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction)

And go to link to create your custom search:

https://cse.google.com/cse/

***Or***

You should go to:

[Google search API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch/overview)

Click to link: **Try this API in APIs Explorer**

Insert your parameter:

- "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"

  - "q=" + keyword (example: "Paris+Hilton")
  - "&cx=" + cx code of your [CSE](https://cse.google.com/cse/all)
  - "&key=" + your authorised API key [In link [API project](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch/overview), click: `A project is needed to enable APIs` +  `Create project`, then go to 'APIs & auth' and activate in 'Custom Search API']
  - "num=" + Number of search results to return (integer)

Press `Execute` to show a result with format JSON.

Comment: I got the result. But there is only showing few results. How to increase the  showing counts of search result.

Comment: At `num` fields in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch/overview will return the number of search results. Please increase this values to get number result from your want.